# IONIC 4 Failed to install cordova-plugin-connectsdk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Im trying to install this plugin 'cordova-plugin-connectsdk' and Im getting this error:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-connectsdk': Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:31:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/project/project/plugins/cordova-plugin-connectsdk/scripts/node_modules/unzip/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

This is my environment info:

✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.0, (and 9 other plugins)

System:

NodeJS : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS High Sierra

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

The main github ConnecdSDK repository is not actively developing now, so try to install one of its forks. For example:

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/boedy/Connect-SDK-Cordova-Plugin.git
```